# Different spam filter method for sasl-auth clients?

Tags: postfix, spam-filter

Using a standard Ubuntu postfix setup (Ubuntu 22.04), I would like to filter mail as follows:

1. Incoming submission and smtps (the vast majority of mail): SPF and RBL checks (I'm using [policyd.pl](https://%20https://github.com/DavidGoodwin/policyd-dnsbl-spf-geoip/blob/master/README.md)), then checked with spamassassin and clamav using Amavis.
2. Sasl-authenticated mail from clients on external networks: rate limited/checked (I'm using `postfwd` for that), then Amavis checks, but **not** SPF and RBL (because we don't want to reject based on clients' sending networks).

Am I right in thinking that if I make the Amavis check the last in the chain, and only have permissive options in the  master.cf "re-entry" listener, I can ensure that mail from sasl-authenticated users don't get the same checks as other mail? For example:

```
smtpd_client_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    # Rate limiting with postfwd: 
    check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    # RBLs, SPF with policyd.pl:
    check_policy_service unix:private/senderCheck

smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks,
    permit_sasl_authenticated,
    ...,
    [various reject_* lines here],
    ...,
    # Amavis checks last:
    content_filter = smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024,
    permit
```

Then have the Amavis "re-entry" config in master.cf as:

```
127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
        -o syslog_name=amavis-reentry
        -o content_filter=
        -o local_recipient_maps=
        -o relay_recipient_maps=
        -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
        -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
        -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
        -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_data_restrictions=
        -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
        -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
        -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
        -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
        -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
        -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
        -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
        -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

**Edit**: For reference, here's the smtpd config in master.cf that I have at the moment:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no
  -o smtpd_discard_ehlo_keywords=silent-discard,dsn

submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.xxx/privkey.pem
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.xxx/fullchain.pem
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING

smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.xxx/privkey.pem
  -o smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/smtp.xxx/fullchain.pem
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is typical to have multiple instances of the `smptd` daemon for different purposes, just like you have the instance on `127.0.0.1:10025` configured for Amavis. In `master.cf` it is possible to override settings on `main.cf` for the said instance.

The [`content_filter`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#content_filter) is not a [`smtpd_recipient_restrictions`](https://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_recipient_restrictions) restriction but a separate configuration parameter.

Here is an example of smtps (`tcp/465`) instance using [Dovecot](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/) for [Postfix SASL](https://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html) authentication:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o { smtpd_client_restrictions = 
         check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10040,
         permit_sasl_authenticated,
         reject
     }
  -o { smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
         reject_non_fqdn_recipient, 
         reject_unknown_recipient_domain, 
         permit_sasl_authenticated,
         reject
     }
  -o content_filter=smtp-amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

Here, the restrictions overrides those in `main.cf`:

- The `smtpd_client_restrictions` removes `policyd.pl` based policies but keeps the the `postfwd` for rate limiting.
- The `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` only has a small set of `reject_` restrictions that are relevant for outbound mail.
- The `permit_mynetworks` are removed from both as this is explicitly for authenticated users.

I would add something like this to prevent users from using each other's addresses:

```
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=reject_sender_login_mismatch
```

The [Postfix and Dovecot SASL](https://doc.dovecot.org/configuration_manual/howto/postfix_and_dovecot_sasl/) documentation has an example for the *submission* protocol, but [RFC 8314](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314) has obsoleted it, and *implicit TLS* ([3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8314#section-3.3)) i.e. *submissions* on port `465` should be used, instead.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise content_filer was a separate configuration parameter. However, I'm unclear how I would configure main.cf to selectively route sasl-auth clients to a separate smptd daemon from non-auth ones though (which is essentially my question).

Comment: You don't. Instead, you would disable SASL authentication from the SMTP on port 25 altogether and configure the clients to use *submissions* on port 465.

Comment: That's what I am doing though (smtp has `smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=no` and submission and smtps are set up in master.cf. Is there a connection between the port the client is using and how its mail gets filtered for spam? You've lost me. Apologies, but can you read my question again? I'll edit for clarity.

Comment: Seems ok. If something is configured in `main.cf` it applies to all instances in `master.cf` unless the same setting is overridden with `-o`.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how it relates to an answer to my question. I'm not asking about having differently configured listeners, I'm asking how to apply selective filtering for them.

Comment: And the example configuration in my answer does exactly that... Should I explain it line by line or what?

Comment: Ah, thanks, I understand now. I initially thought you meant `content_filter` took effect globally.